# How to find 4 unknowns?

Tags: equation-solving

There are 4 unknowns constants: `a`,`b`,`c`,`p`. The variable is `phi` and the result is `d`.

For `phi={13,23,45,73}` the results are    `d={32.08754292290807,32.1136624112758,32.1728430675844,32.2430287624866}`

The equation is:

```
(c/0.3048*((1+(a*p/(b*c))*(sin(phi*pi/180))^2))/sqrt(1-sqrt(1-b^2/a^2)*
((sin(phi*pi/180))^2))) = d
```

How can I solve it in Mathematica?

Comment: Have a look at `Solve`.

Answer (score 1):

If I decipher your parentheses correctly, this is just a second order algebraic equation in `u` if you set `u=Sin[phi]^2`. So you may directly define a function

```
f[a_,b_,c_,p_] := Block[{A,B,C,Delta,U},
                         A=...;B=...;C=...;Delta=Sqrt[B^2-4*A C];
                         U=...;
                         phi=ArcSin[Sqrt[U]];]
```

which first solves the equation in u, then takes the arcsin.

Comment: Note that `C` is protected!

Comment: @sebhofer It's inside a `Block` :)

Comment: @rm-rf Damn ...

Comment: @rm-rf http://www.clker.com/cliparts/G/b/l/l/m/l/alphabet-block-c-md.png

Comment: Thank you,

I' m able to do second order algebraic equation 
but I don't  known how to solve it.
Can you provide  exact code (or How can I put there all 4 solutions i.e. (For phi={13,23,45,73} the results are d=32.08754292290807,32.1136624112758,32.1728430675844,32.2430287624866}))

Thank you in advance.
Milos